# Proof of a Bromwich integral formula

Tags: complex-analysis, laplace-transform

I am trying to prove that:

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i }\int_{\alpha-i\infty}^{\alpha+i\infty}\frac{(\log s)^{n}}{s}e^{sx}ds=(-1)^{n}\frac{d^{n}}{dz^{n}}\frac{x^{z}}{\Gamma(1+z)}\left.\begin{matrix}
\\ 
\\ 
\end{matrix}\right|_{z=0}$$
Where $\alpha>0$.

Comment: Use $~\ln^ns=\bigg[\dfrac{d^n}{dk^n}~s^k\bigg]_{k=0}~$ in conjunction with the integral expression for the [$\Gamma$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function), and see where it leads you.

Comment: @Lucian i don't follow your reasoning !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use the Laplace transform formula:
$$(-1)^{n}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{d^{n}}{dz^{n}}\frac{x^{z}}{\Gamma(1+z)}e^{-sx}dx\left.\begin{matrix}\\ \\ \end{matrix}\right|_{z=0}=(-1)^{n}\frac{d^{n}}{dz^{n}}\frac{1}{\Gamma(1+z)}\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{z}e^{-sx}dx\left.\begin{matrix}\\ \\ \end{matrix}\right|_{z=0}$$
$$=(-1)^{n}\frac{d^{n}}{dz^{n}}\frac{1}{\Gamma(1+z)}\frac{\Gamma(1+z)}{s^{z+1}}\left.\begin{matrix}\\ \\ \end{matrix}\right|_{z=0}=\frac{(\log s)^{n}}{s}$$
And thus,by Bromwich integral formula:
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i }\int_{\alpha-i\infty}^{\alpha+i\infty}\frac{(\log s)^{n}}{s}e^{sx}ds=(-1)^{n}\frac{d^{n}}{dz^{n}}\frac{x^{z}}{\Gamma(1+z)}\left.\begin{matrix}\\ \\ \end{matrix}\right|_{z=0}$$